# Loading text data in R package

Tags: r, package

I'm working on an R package and having a terrible time trying to load data for internal use in the package.

The package is set up with `LazyData: false` and the data itself is in a file called `params.csv` file in the `data` directory.  If, within one of my functions, I write the following:

```
data(params, envir=environment())
```

Then the file loads and I can use it in the code.  *But* as stated in the docs, it's loaded with `read.table(file, sep=";")` and I have character values that I don't want treated as factors.  If this was a normal `read.table` call, then I'd add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and everything would be fine.

The *Note* section of `?data` suggests that you can use an R file in the data folder to manually do this loading, but I can't figure it out.  I've tried making a file called `params.r` in the data directory as follows:

```
read.table("params.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

but when it loads, R complains that the `read.table` function is not found.  Again, the docs say that `data` somehow loads `utils` before sourcing the file, but when I put a standard `library(utils)` call at the start of my script, it complains that `utils` can't be found.

I even tried setting `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` before the `data` call but that doesn't seem to work either.  The data are still loaded as factors.

Are there any package experts out there that know how to work around this?  I'd rather not have to manually kludge everything to the right format after loading; it just seems inelegant.

Comment: Get your data into the form that you want it, then use `save`. Use the saved .Rdata representation in your package.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but I want to keep it plain text so I can easily edit it without opening R.  The data is a table of configuration parameters, e.g. URLs that frequently change.

Comment: If you read the **Note** section of `? data` carefully, you'll see that the calling the .R file first only works because of search order in the directory. Your data file needs an extension that comes after the extension of your .R file (e.g., .txt), or an entirely different name.

Comment: But that's not the problem.  The issue is that the function `read.table` isn't found.

Comment: Did you solve your problem (please post the answer here :-). Perhaps a `utils::read.table` would have been the solution. [Writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages) has a note on this: *"Note that R code should be “self-sufficient” and not make use of extra functionality provided by the package, so that the data file can also be used without having to load the package or its namespace."*